# Insert rows and split string delimited with semicolons

Tags: vba, split, insert, row

My values are in column H and the range of the entire table is A:N. I got the below table from the net and modified this to meet my requirement. However, it seems that I am missing out on something - would be really helpful if someone could help me figure that out. Here is the code that I used and it does nothing to my table. As I am new to VBA, a descriptive commentary would be really helpful to understand the code.

```
Sub splitByColH()
    Dim r As Range, i As Long, ar As Variant
    Set r = Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("H999999").End(xlUp)
    Do While r.Row > 1
        ar = Split(r.Value, ";")
        If UBound(ar) >= 0 Then r.Value = ar(0)
        For i = UBound(ar) To 1 Step -1
            r.EntireRow.Copy
            r.Offset(1).EntireRow.Insert
            r.Offset(1).Value = ar(i)
        Next
        Set r = r.Offset(-1)
    Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: `For i = UBound(ar) To LBound(ar) Step -1` instead of `1`, because the arrays could be 0-based.(depends on your settings and Option Base 1).

Comment: It would be really helpful to understand your issue, too!

Comment: Hi, thanks. So here is my table .

Comment: Hi, thanks. can't attach the table...let me try to explain this here .. So I have strings/ numbers in A:N range which is dynamic. In H column there are words separated by semicolon like Microsoft; IBM. My objective is the code will search through the H column and whenever it will find such strings separated by semicolons, it will create additional rows. For 'Microsoft; IBM', it will add one additional row ...the first row will have Microsoft and the additional one will have IBM in it. Rest all the columns will be same for both the items/ rows. Many thanks for all your help.

Answer (score 1):

```
Sub splitByColH()
    Dim r As Range, i As Long, ar As Variant
    Set r = Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("H999999").End(xlUp) ' Set r to be the last cell used in col H

    Do While r.Row > 1 ' As long as the r row is > 1

        ar = Split(r.Value, ";") ' Take r cell (last in H col) and create an array of its values when split by ;
        If UBound(ar) >= 0 Then r.Value = ar(0) ' As long as ar contains more than one element
        For i = UBound(ar) To 1 Step -1 ' Step through all elements from last to first
            r.EntireRow.Copy ' Copy the entire row where r is
            r.Offset(1).EntireRow.Insert ' Paste it (insert) one row below
            r.Offset(1).Value = ar(i) ' Set the H col of the new row to be the i'th element of ar
        Next
        Set r = r.Offset(-1) ' point r to where it is minus one row
    Loop
End Sub
```

I have explained what your code does right now. It makes little sense, so I suppose you have a logic error somewhere. If you explain the wished result in more detail, it will be possible to give you a better answer..

Comment: The error that I am getting with the following code is Run-time error '1004' - Application-defined or object-defined error

Comment: On what row do you get it?

Comment: When I just run the code, I see this error.. the code does not run properly (not specific to any row). My data table starts from A9 with H column having the string with ';'

Comment: If you put this snippet in a new workbook and put some simple data there - do you still get the error?

Comment: Thanks all, it worked fine. The problem was with the data set, which was formatted weirdly. The code worked fine post that.